# My project just stop working after a while

Tags: animation, particles, soft-body

I'm doing some animation with bouncing balls and hair, everything is fine but after a while, when I work on projects, the objects stop to follow my commands. It happens all the times, and what was good a minute ago now doesn't work anymore, like this object crashing and not following the property about soft boby, just like the particles don't follow anymore the objects even if pin goal is set to 50.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, nobody answered, but that's it.
I abandoned Blender 1.9 and I get back to Blender 1.83
now everything is perfect.